# Getting the output context from the fallback intent in fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es

I've got a few intents. They all just use a single fallback intent and this fallback intent has the webhook enabled.

In the fallback function what I was hoping to do is switch on the output context and then determine what should happen next depending on which intent the fallback came from.

But the line

```
var context = request.body.queryResult.outputContexts;
```

When debugged to the console gets output:

```
[ { name: 'projects/xxxxproj-xxxx/agent/sessions/xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/contexts/xxxxxxx-context' } ]
```

For the switch statement i just want the last bit with the xxxxx-context. Am I going to have to split that up to get the output context?

In the "Diagnostic Info" section I am a bit surprised there is no reference to the intent from which the fallback came and the only way to work it out seems to be using the outputcontext but as show above that is quite a long string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the context name is just the last part of that path. Most libraries will take care of that for you, but if you're working with the JSON directly, you need to do this yourself.

There is no reference to "the Intent from which the fallback came" because this isn't quite the model of what an Intent is. Intents represent what the user has said or done, not the current state of the conversation or where you are in the conversation. That current state *is* represented by Contexts, should you choose to set them.

In that sense, how you use the contexts can vary. They can store parameters, so are a good way to keep information between rounds of a conversation, and you can use them the way you are - to see what state the conversation is in general. But they also take on additional uses when defining Intents.

In an Intent definition, the Intent will only be triggered if *all* the Contexts listed in the Input Context field are set (ie - have a lifespan greater than 0). Dialogflow uses this when it makes followup Intents, for example, and it is common so you can do things such as have "help" trigger different Intents based on Context. In an Output Context, it will automatically capture all of the parameters specified in the Intent, including those filled in by the user's response, so this can be an easy way to remember what the user has said from round to round.

To answer your question in the comments - it doesn't specifically say *which* Intents were previously triggered, or which most recently, although if you're consistent in how you use your Output Contexts and what lifespan you give them, you can use it this way. What it does say is in what *state* your conversation is in, which is generally much better anyway.

Remember - Intents represent what a user has said or done. It doesn't represent anything else about the conversation. Only the state of the system represents that, and one tool we have to control that state is through Contexts.

Comment: Thanks. I was just going to use a regex to get the output context, unless there are any better suggestions. And i've read up about contexts -  can i just confirm that input contexts are used to specify which intent should be active eg. if i have multiple intents that have yes or no as a response i can use an input context to isolate a particular intent where output contexts tell me which intent has most recently been active.

Comment: A regex is probably overkill, but works. I've updated my answer to discuss contexts a little more.

Comment: Thx @Prisoner. Still a bit confused. According to the docs "...an output context tells Dialogflow to activate a context if it's not already active or to maintain the context after the intent is matched."  I'm using the inline editor and fulfilment. I have three intents intent1, intent2, intent3. Each intent takes yes or no as an answer. i want intent1 to be activated first then 2 then 3. I have set each output context as intent1-outputcxt, etc. Then  in fulfilment I set agent.context.set({ "name": 'intent2-context', "lifespan": 0 }); for example to isolate intent2 for the the yes or no answer

Comment: Is that the right way to isolate and activate a specific intent? And if so then I don't quite get what an input-context does and the docs state.."an input context tells Dialogflow to match the intent only if the end-user expression is a close match and if the context is active" - that confuses me a bit. Thanks

Comment: This is getting a little bit too complicated to answer via comments. Can I suggest you open a new question showing the code and screen shots of the contexts and discussing how you want them to work?